# SQL query for joining four tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am a newbie to writing SQL queries, Can anyone please help me write SQL query for below conditions and joins?

I have 4 tables let's say `T1`, `T2`, `T3` and `T4`

```
T1 have columns a1(PK), a2, a3, a4

T2 have columns b1(PK), a1(FK), b2

T3 have columns c1(PK), a1(FK)

T4 have columns d1(PK), c1(FK), d2, d3
```

Conditions :

1. I want to have all columns from `T1` when `a4 == "xx"`
2. If `T1.a1 == T2.a1` and `T1.a2 == "x"`, then I want `b2` to be included in the final result as **new column**.
3. If `T3.c1 == T4.c1` and `T4.d2 == "y"`, then take value from `d3` which needs to be joined to step4
4. If `T1.a1 == T3.a1` and `T1.a2 == "z"`, then value from `d3` (step 3) should be included in the final result's **new column**

I am trying to solve as below,  but I dont know how to add value `d3` from step 3 to `b2` in the final result.

```
select T1.a1,T1.a2,T1.a3,T1.a4,T2.b2 from
T1
left join T2 on T1.a1 == T2.a1 AND T1.a2 == "x"
left join ( 
    select T3.a1,T4.d3 from T3,T4
    where T3.c1 == T4.c1 AND T4.d2 == "y") 
) joined on joined.a1 == T1.a1 and T1.a2 == "z"
where a4 == "xx";
```

Sample data

```
T1 table :

a1 |  a2 | a3 | a4 |
1  |  x  | cat| xx |
2  |  aa | hat| la |
3  |  z  | mat| xx |

T2 table : 

b1  |  b2  | a1 | 
11  |  984 | 1  | 
22  |  234 | 2  | 

T3 table : 

c1   |  a1 | 
111  |  3  | 
222  |  7  | 

T4 table : 

d1    |  d2  | d3  | c1  |
1111  |  y   | 100 | 111 |
2222  |  yy  | 200 | 333 |


Expected Result : 

a1  |  a2  | a3   | a4 | new column
1   |  x   | cat  | xx | 984 (from T2.b2)
3   |  z   | mat  | xx | 100 (from T4.d3)
```

Please help me to correct my query. Appreciate your help.

Comment: showing sample data and sample results would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "included in the column b2 (step 2) in final result"?

Comment: @danblack Thank you for replying. I have updated my question with sample data and the expected final result

Comment: @Nick Thank you for replying. I have updated my question. I want new column in final result with data from b2 and d3.

Comment: If `T1.a2` is not equal to `x` or `z`, what do you want in the new column? or do you not want any results? What about when `T1.a2 = 'z'`, but `T4.d2 != 'y'`?

Comment: @Nick I dont want results in the new column for both the cases you mentioned.

Comment: Do you still want the rows returned, just with an empty/zero value in that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want *no* results when your conditions are not met, this query will give you the results you want. It uses a `CASE` expression to select the correct value for `new column`, using the value of `a2` to decide whether to use `b2` or `d3` for that value. Rows which don't meet your conditions are excluded by the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT T1.*, 
       CASE WHEN T1.a2 = 'x' THEN T2.b2
            WHEN T1.a2 = 'z' THEN T4.d3
       END AS `new column`
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.a1 = T1.a1
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.a1 = T1.a1
LEFT JOIN T4 ON T4.c1 = T3.c1
WHERE a4 = 'xx' AND (a2 = 'x' OR a2 = 'z' AND d2 = 'y')
ORDER BY a1
```

Output:

```
a1  a2  a3  a4  new column
1   x   cat xx  984
3   z   mat xx  100
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eFhjQgPCxjAHpH9TV5o3bv/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as:

```
SELECT T1.*,
       (CASE WHEN T1.a2 = 'x'
             THEN (SELECT T2.b2
                   FROM T2
                   WHERE T2.a1 = T1.a1
                  )
             ELSE (SELECT T4.d3
                   FROM T3 JOIN
                        T4
                        ON T4.c1 = T3.c1
                   WHERE T3.a1 = T1.a1 AND T4.d2 = 'y'
                  )
        END) as new_column
FROM T1
WHERE T1.a4 = 'xx' AND T1.a2 IN ('x', 'z')
ORDER BY T1.a1;
```

This assumes that at most one row matches from each of the two possibilities.

If so, I find that the logic here better captures your intent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the query